Concatenate 2 values from different file
I am having 2 files with me where one csv file having below data
CIDR,Netmask
/30,255.255.255.252
/29,255.255.255.248
/28,255.255.255.240
/27,255.255.255.224
/26,255.255.255.192
/25,255.255.255.128
/24,255.255.255.0
/23,255.255.254.0
/22,255.255.252.0
/21,255.255.248.0
/20,255.255.240.0
/19,255.255.224.0
/18,255.255.192.0
/17,255.255.128.0
/16,255.255.0.0
/15,255.254.0.0
/14,255.252.0.0
/13,255.248.0.0
/12,255.240.0.0
/11,255.224.0.0
/10,255.192.0.0
/9,255.128.0.0
/8,255.0.0.0
/7,254.0.0.0
/6,252.0.0.0
/5,248.0.0.0
/4,240.0.0.0
/3,224.0.0.0
/2,192.0.0.0
/1,128.0.0.0
/0,0.0.0.0

the other file(excel sheet) have data like below
Network         VLanID    Environment       Gateway       Netmask
10.155.96.0/23  2096      ETHERNET          10.155.96.1   255.255.254.0
10.155.98.0/23  2098      ETHERNET          10.155.98.1   255.255.254.0
10.155.100.0/23 2100      ETHERNET          10.155.100.1  255.255.255.224


I need to create a new column where based on "Netmask" value, get the CIDR value from the csv file and generate a colum value like "255.255.254.0 (/23)"
expected output
Network         VLanID    Environment   Gateway       Netmask         newmask
10.155.96.0/23  2096      ETHERNET      10.155.96.1   255.255.254.0   255.255.254.0 (/23)
10.155.98.0/23  2098      ETHERNET      10.155.98.1   255.255.254.0   255.255.254.0 (/23)
10.155.100.0/23 2100      ETHERNET      10.155.100.1  255.255.255.224 255.255.255.224 (/27)


please let me know how can I do this

You can use the VLOOKUP function.

@AanchalMehrotra: as the netmask is not in the first column, I think the function XLookup() wil be needed instead.

Use Add-Member to add the new column : $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName newmask -NotePropertyValue $mask

Please add the code that you've tried to your question

Especially since you wrote the data is in two different CSV files, you can both read them in and create your desired output using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Make note of your file names and edit the M code accordingly
Open each file seperately using Data=>From Text/CSV

This will create two separate queries in PQ with the file names as the query names


From the Power Query interface, select Home=>Combine=>Merge Queries=>Merge Queries as New and select NetMask as the column to match on.
Add a custom column to extract the data in the format you wish.

[CIDRNetMask][Netmask]{0} & " (" & [CIDRNetMask][CIDR]{0}& ")"


Remove the extraneous column

You may also, after you have created your new Merge query, go to Home=>Advanced Editor and paste the M code below into the window that opens.
let

//Change `VLAN` and  `CIDRNetMask` to the actual query names of the csv file names you previsouly loaded.
//Note that the Order is important.  VLAN is your three row table csv file in your question. CIDRNetMask is the file with the list of CIDR's
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(VLAN, {"Netmask"}, CIDRNetMask, {"Netmask"}, "CIDRNetMask", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Add newmaks" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "newmask", each [CIDRNetMask][Netmask]{0} & " (" & [CIDRNetMask][CIDR]{0}& ")", type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add newmaks",{"CIDRNetMask"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"



You can use INDEX MATCH formula in combination with "CONCAT" to add the brackets "()"
Copy your data from CSV file to excel file and use the below formula in column F (newmask):

=CONCAT(E2," (",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$32,MATCH(Sheet2!E2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$32,0),1),")")


I copied your CSV data in "Sheet1" and Excel data in "Sheet2"
Hope this helps!
